# SQL/Presto expanding a list column into multiple rows

Tags: sql, list, presto, expand

Given a hive table like

```
a  |   b
----------
1  |  [1,2,3]
2  |  [2,3]
```

How can I create a secondary table like

```
a | b
------
1 | 1
1 | 2 
1 | 3 
2 | 2 
2 | 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a textbook case for [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (a, b) AS (
    VALUES (1, array[1,2,3]),
    (2, array[2,3])
) 

-- query
select a, bb
from dataset
cross join unnest(b) as t(bb)
order by a, bb -- to pretify output
```

Output:

| a | bb |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |